# click textbox (to enter characters), when submit is clicked

Tags: textbox, click, submit, enter

If click the submit button or `a`-element then automatically the input text is clicked.

```js
function send()
{
    var txt = document.getElementById("textbox");
    txt.click();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" style="width:90%;">
<a id="send" style="display:none;" onclick="send()" href="">Send</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the value of "textbox" with the following instruction:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("textbox");
```

Then you need to correct it like this:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
```

Comment: well, my problem is that if i click on the submit button, then i save some details to the database (<- this is not the problem, now) and then the mouse clicks automaticly in the textbox, so that i can type directly without clicking self into the input text

Comment: could  document.getElementById("textbox").focus(); be a solution ?

Comment: Thanks it works ! I did not realize that I could fix focus with javascript !

Comment: Yep, Javascript is a very complete/powerful language ;)